# Are you cloud-ready?

Tags: word-usage

When I was watching TV, I heard the rugby manager say, "Are you cloud-ready?" in the commercial related to the computer.  I haven't heard "cloud-ready" before but I can guess its meaning.

My question is if you can change "cloud" to any other words such as "Are you exam-ready?", or "I am trip-ready."  How does it sound?  If you have any other examples using "-ready", please pick up some.

Comment: You can say any of those things in advertising-speak.  It's not "formal" lingo, however.

Comment: @HotLicks is correct. This is really advertising English, but some terms such as *battle-ready*, *combat-ready* and *oven-ready* have become common usage.

Comment: Yes. XXX-ready is just a cool way of saying/ asking whether you "equipped/ enabled" (at you end) to perform a given task.

Comment: So does that mean you can basically add any word if you want like 'exam - ready'?

Comment: You example of trip-ready would be more idiomatically written as travel-ready.  "Are you travel-ready?"  "Yes, my luggage is packed and my passport is in my purse."

Comment: Btw the *you* is presumably directed at business stakeholders not at Joe Public.

Comment: I disagree with @HotLicks and Mick that this is advertising-speak (aka marketing-speak). (I hate advertising-speak, BTW.) This is ordinary English. Just as you can use suffix *-wise* generally, so you can use suffix *-ready* or suffix *-speak* generally. This is a common way to coin perfectly understandable English words. Whether you might **want** to use a particular such word depends on you and your context.

Comment: *Cloud-ready* is marketing/advertising oriented only because "The Cloud" is currently something important to (part of) the world of marketing/advertising. But certainly adding suffix *-ready* is not especially about marketing or advertising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ready_5), *ready* as suffix is

> added to nouns to create adjectives that show what something is ready for.
>   *"camera-ready copy"*
>   *"Seven Slimdown Rules to get you Bikini-Ready in a Week"*

So it's okay to say "exam-ready" in place of "ready for exam". But it would not usually be used in formal contexts.

According to an [article published on IBM website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1404_brown/1404_brown.html), *cloud-ready*, for applications, can be explained as:

> An application is cloud-ready if it can be effectively deployed into either a public or private cloud. That is, the application must be designed so that it can take advantage of the capabilities that are provided by the platform-as-a-service (PaaS) layer on which it runs.

Comment: Thnks for all your comments.  I'll try to be careful when I used this "-ready" phrase.

Comment: What does that green check mark mean?

Comment: @Akihiro it means that my answer was helpful.

Comment: @Akihiro Click the up-triangle if you think the answer was helpful. Click the green tick if you accept that as the answer to your question. If there are multiple answers, you (and all other registered users) may up-vote or down-vote as many of them as you like, but you may only *accept* one of them. You're allowed to change your mind about the accepted answer, though. Only the user who posted the question is allowed to accept an answer to that question.